How to create and sign Transaction using Python
I have configured three signers to sign or approve transactions in Safe wallet, so i want to implement in my project which is in python. Can you provide me Python implementation or any documentation for this functionality

There's safe-eth-py that might be helpful: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py
Documentation for safe-eth-py: https://safe-eth-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
